# How to force maxima to display common factors of matrix elements as product of matrix

Tags: maxima

The result of the following matrix expression

```
F : invert(ident(2) - 1/J*matrix(['diff(u,x), 'diff(u,y)],['diff(v,x), 'diff(v,y)]));
```

produces the following output, noting the common denominator of all matrix elements.

[image]

I'd like to display the result in a simpler form where the common denominator appears (highlighted) as a product of the matrix. I've tried to achieve this manually, as shown below, but the result is the same:

```
matrix([num(F[1,1]), num(F[1,2])/J], [num(F[2,1])/J, num(F[2,2])])/denom(F[1,1]);
```

Is there a workaround, as F is used in other expressions and the complicated form makes those expressions even more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a symbol (`'s`) to replace the common part:

```
a: denom(F[1,1]);
newF: F*a*'(1/a)
```

[image: newF]

and replace it again with `newF, a=a` when needed.